# TextView text appending

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

That's my problem: I'd like to build a calculator, like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calculator-for-ipad-free/id398129933), So I put a text view and some buttons in the window but, now that's the code:

Document.h

```
//
//  Document.m
//  TheCalcolator
//
//  Created by Imac on 15/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Imac. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Document.h"
#import "FunctionalManager.h"

@implementation Document

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    return @"Document";
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
}

+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Insert code here to write your document to data of the specified type. If outError != NULL, ensure that you create and set an appropriate error when returning nil.
    // You can also choose to override -fileWrapperOfType:error:, -writeToURL:ofType:error:, or -writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error: instead.
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"UnimplementedMethod" reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is unimplemented", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)] userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Insert code here to read your document from the given data of the specified type. If outError != NULL, ensure that you create and set an appropriate error when returning NO.
    // You can also choose to override -readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error: or -readFromURL:ofType:error: instead.
    // If you override either of these, you should also override -isEntireFileLoaded to return NO if the contents are lazily loaded.
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"UnimplementedMethod" reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is unimplemented", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)] userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)aggiungiuno:(id)sender
{
    FunctionalManager *func = [[FunctionalManager init] alloc];

    [func aggiungitesto:@"1" allaView:textView];
}

@end
```

and that's FunctionalManager.m :

```
//
//  FunctionalManager.m
//  TheCalcolator
//
//  Created by Imac on 15/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Imac. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FunctionalManager.h"

@implementation FunctionalManager

-(void)aggiungitesto:(NSString *)daString allaView:(NSTextView *)view
{
    NSString *testoAttuale = view.string;

    view.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", testoAttuale, daString];

}

@end
```

Can you help me to understand where's the error? Because when I build it that's what xcode shows me: http://it.tinypic.com/r/2z9d6qd/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
FunctionalManager *func = [[FunctionalManager alloc] init];
```

You've got `alloc`/`init` backwards.